# Looking for a word that describes a word with a positive connotation substituted for a negative word

Tags: single-word-requests

So I was watching Life with Lisa Ling, the episode about sugar daddies (lol). Almost every other "sugar baby" used the word "mentor" instead of "sugar daddy". What do you call the word (with positive connotation) that is substituted for another word (essentially negative) in order to make whatever they are trying to explain/sell sound better.

In the example above, what is the word, "mentor," called?

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry. Didn't see your post till I'd posted mine.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian My feeling is always: if you posted in good faith and someone else put it in a comment let it stand, collect the rep, and smile.

Comment: @David M OK I'm smiling. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Euphemism](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/euphemism): A mild or indirect word or expression substituted for one considered to be too harsh or blunt when referring to something unpleasant or embarrassing.
- Lexico

Comment: Good answer, by which I mean the one I immediately thought of myself . . . +1.